# How to mock generic method using mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a generic method but getting class cast exception, no matter what I try. Class under testing is

```
public class TClass {
    private byte[] data;
    public <T extends SInterface> T asObject(T item){
        item.SMethod(this.getData());
        return item;
    }

    private byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

while the **testing class** is

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TClassTest {
    @Mock
    SSInterface sClass;
    @Mock
    SObject sObject;

    TClass tClass = new TClass();


    @org.junit.Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void asObject() {
        Mockito.when(tClass.asObject(new SSClass())).thenReturn(sClass);
    }
}
```

Other **helper classes** and **interface** are:

```
 public interface SInterface {
    public void SMethod(byte[] in);
}



public interface SSInterface extends SInterface {
}


public class SSClass implements SSInterface {
    @Override
    public void SMethod(byte[] in) {
    }
}

public class SObject {
}
```

The error I am getting is :

> Cannot resolve method thenReturn(generic.SSInterface)

if I use `Mockito.when(tClass.asObject(new SSClass())).thenReturn(new SSClass());`

I get 
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

```
at generic.TClassTest.asObject(TClassTest.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:78)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:84)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have incompatible types and it has nothing to do with mockito. `asObject()` returns the same type as it receives and it has to be of `SInterface` type.

Depending on what you trying to achive ou can either return the instance of `SSClasss`:

```
Mockito.when(tClass.asObject(new SSClass())).thenReturn( new SSClass());
```

or you can make `TClass` extend `SInterface` and then:

`Mockito.when(tClass.asObject(tClass)).thenReturn(tClass);`

Comment: `Mockito.when(tClass.asObject(new SSClass())).thenReturn(new SSClass());` does not work

Comment: Bcs `tClasss` is not a mock. Add `@Mock TClass tClass;` to make it work. But then again it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to test TClass.asObject() but verifying sClass.SMethod() is called.

```
@org.junit.Test
public void asObject() {
        final SSInterface sut = new SSClass();

        final SSInterface returned = sut.asObject(sClass);

        assertEquals(sClass, returned);
        Mockito.verify(sClass).SMethod(any());    
}
```